# iText7 pagesize not working with paragraph

Tags: pdf, itext7

I have use iText7 for pdf convert, used Page Size it is working well, but paragraph not allow to work with page size, Guys can you please help for this issue, here attached a code sample. thank you for your support.

```
PageSize objPageSize = new PageSize(5, 5);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\Test.pdf);
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, objPageSize);
document.SetMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
Paragraph objParagraph = new Paragraph("HEADER");
document.Add(objParagraph);
document.Close();
```

Comment: *"paragraph not allow to work with page size"* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Thank you mkl for your suggestion, using .Net Core with itext7, purpose is need to generate PDF which contain text details and barcode for Zebra printer size (this is not a A4 size page) PDF generate, again thank you for your support

Comment: Looks like "not allow to work with page size" means that the result appears to be empty/blank

Answer (score 0):

Your page size is too small even for a single glyph to fit. Make it at least 10x10 and set the paragraph font size to e.g. `0.5`:

```
PageSize objPageSize = new PageSize(10, 10);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\Test.pdf);
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, objPageSize);
document.SetMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
Paragraph objParagraph = new Paragraph("HEADER").SetFontSize(0.5f);
document.Add(objParagraph);
document.Close();
```

You are going to get the following visual result then:

[image: result]

**UPD** top left corner, 6x6:

```
PageSize objPageSize = new PageSize(6, 6);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\Test.pdf);
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, objPageSize);
document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
Paragraph objParagraph = new Paragraph("HEADER").SetFontSize(0.5f).SetMargin(0);
document.Add(objParagraph);
document.Close();
```

Result:

[image: result 6x6]

Comment: Alexey Subach thank you for looking for this, in Zebra printer barcode label size around 6x6, and it start to print from top left corner, is there any way to implement for same, i want 6x6 label size with text and barcode both on label, your effort is appreciated,

Comment: your attached image not a 6x6 pdf render, this is A4 size, i have attached 6x6 for reference, in 6x6 it not allow to render paragraph combination of text and barcode, please see image

Comment: A4 size is rectangular, my images are clearly squares